# Is output of a "dir" command same in all distributions of Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm preparing a batch compiling sh file in Ubuntu. It is using dir command to get a list of files (and some string processing to extract names). But this may not be the best way (but easy enough) of getting list.

Question: do all Linux distros answer "dir" command same?

```
dir /usr/lib/nvidia-*

/usr/lib/nvidia-396:
alt_ld.so.conf             libnvidia-cfg.so.396.54
bin                libnvidia-compiler.so
ld.so.conf             libnvidia-compiler.so.1
libEGL_nvidia.so.0         libnvidia-compiler.so.396.54
```

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. [su] or [unix.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the dir tool should work the same across any distribution, provided the distribution doesn't have its own modified version or has this tool missing etc.

You might find this helpful for some background into dir tool

https://www.howtoforge.com/linux-dir-command/

Comment: Are there OS-specific default options that can make dir command show data differently, different order, etc?

Comment: Usually no, the dir tool should be pretty standard. That being said a developer could write their own distribution to behave however they like, so I couldn't say "every distribution will have this tool and it will work exactly the same as yours"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tree` command to get all files and filter whatever you want.

`tree -f -i .|grep .*\.py$` here it greps all .py files.

[here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tree)'s tree doc

example:

```
root@fdada3432377:/usr/src/app# tree -f -i conn* |grep .*\.py$
connection/__init__.py
```

Comment: I was getting list of names into an array. Does tree give a more "trusted" type of output? Also I don't have tree installed. Can I expect it is less occured in pcs than dir does?